# AMPScript in footer not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

Trying to add a content block to the settings footer here:
[image]

But it doesn't seem to work.
I even tried to copy past the code and nothing...
Is there a built-in limitation?

Here is the way I add the code block:

```
%%[
/*
Content block location: Shared Content\Admin\IER\IER_Campaign_Update_Email_Code
*/
ContentBlockByID("62658")
]%%
```

Here is the code:

```
%%[
    set @tsdid = Lookup("_Job", "TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID", "JobID", jobid)
    set @version_id = Lookup("_JourneyActivity", "VersionID", "JourneyActivityObjectID", @tsdid)
    set @journey_id = Lookup("_Journey", "JourneyName", "VersionID", @version_id)

  IF not empty(emailname_) AND jobid!='0' THEN
    InsertDE(
      'IER_Campaign_Update',
      'TrackID',
      GUID(),
      'JobID',
      jobid,
      'SubscriberKey',
      _subscriberkey,
      'EmailName',
      emailname_,
      'MC_Journey_Name__c',
      @journey_id,
      'SentDate',
      now()
    )
  ENDIF
]%%
```